# BootstrapTable search configuration and css to search is not getting applied. BootstrapTable Search options?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<BootstrapTable id="importQuestionBankTable" data={this.props.questionBankList} striped hover version='4' search selectRow={selectRowProp} options={options} insertRow>
     <TableHeaderColumn height='100px' width='70%' isKey dataField='query' dataFormat={this.surveyQuestionsFormatter} dataSort>Questions</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

I need help in solving this problem. I am using BootstrapTable which has a search attribute. I cannot modify it or apply any type of configurations to it such as CSS and alignment. Is there any way to do this? Please refer the below link. In the image the search bar is coming from BootstrapTable. But when I try to give CSS or align it, it does not reflect any changes.

[image: BootStrapTable]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the *data-search-selector* attribute and link it to a element you create and style with your preferences. Something like:

```
<input type="text" class="myOwnStyle" id="customSearch" placeholder="customSearch">

<table
    data-toggle="table"
    data-search="true"
    data-search-selector="#customSearch">
    
</table>
```